# Fail to plug Samsung Galaxy S2 to Ubuntu 11.04 using USB (with or without debug mode)

Tags: android, samsung, udev, usb-drive

The scenario was working few days ago. I was able to plug my Galaxy S2 to my laptop mount it under Linux Mint 11.04 (Ubuntu), I mean it was fully detected and working.
Now, the android device detect the USB plugging, but the laptop doesn't "react" anymore: nothing in `lsusb` and errors in `dmesg | tail` log:

```
[56946.981778] usb 2-1.5: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 33
[56947.061827] usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[56947.251592] usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[56947.441519] usb 2-1.5: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 34
[56947.521649] usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[56947.711412] usb 2-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[56947.901294] usb 2-1.5: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 35
[56948.320944] usb 2-1.5: device not accepting address 35, error -32
[56948.401060] usb 2-1.5: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 36
[56948.820710] usb 2-1.5: device not accepting address 36, error -32
[56948.820963] hub 2-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 5
```

P.S.: I add the UDEV rules without success:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules
```

With that rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8",ATTRS{idProduct}=="6640", MODE="0666", OWNER="root",GROUP="myUser", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

Comment: Looks similar to my issue yesterday (though it works in normal mode, just not Odin mode): http://askubuntu.com/questions/54555/samsung-galaxy-s2-in-download-mode-breaks-lsusb

Comment: I tried different :
rules (http://klaus.ede.hih.au.dk/index.php/Android_Development#Connect_devices_to_Linux_boxes, http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), 
 cables and laptop. But I still got the same error message as above.

Comment: Following the answers given have you been able to resolve your problem or do you still require an answer? Can you please update your question?

Comment: I solve this issue by returning my phone to the customer service.

Comment: I really don't get why this question got closed as "too localized"... I'm sure that if the OP hadn't specified the phone + OS specs then people would have asked him to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying adb access please have a look at http://hailubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/12/adb-not-detecting-adroid-device.html

For mass storage access try using another cable (I have issues with stock cable so I use the one that came with nexus one) I've SGS Epic. If you have gparted installed you can run it after connecting phone in mass storage mode and see if it shows up in gparted. I've to mount few USB devices manually. If even gparted can't show phone connected (mass storage only) then its cable to be blamed.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my issue. The phone doesn't show up in lsusb anymore and I used to work as your link described.
The issue seems to came earlier in the process of connecting the device, see the `dmesg | tail` log

Comment: in that case please try changing your cable (if you have spare or borrow for a while) my samsung cable was working fine for few days but then I had to use nexus one as it stopped working.